# How to query search through a tree in java

Tags: java, recursion, tree

I am trying to return a list of Strings of the nodes whose data is "directory" by returning its true name as children.get(0).children.get(0).data

So far, when I go through the tree, it can find the nodes and add the data that Im looking for, but as I add those strings in the List and them System.out.println the list out, the list changes. It can reset, remove Strings, etc.

Right before the return statement, I print off the list. It is not what gets returned.

!!!beforeoutput[Pictures, Pictures2.0, Pictures, Pictures2.0] //print of the list

!!!beforeoutput[Movies and Pictures, Movies, Pictures] //print of the list

getdirectories [Movies and Pictures, Movies, Pictures] //actual output

Someone had told me to define the list in the global scope, and I did, and literally nothing happened.

**I guess what I'm asking for is how does one properly query through a tree. I know its recursive, but when adding the values in the list, it messes up the list.**

My method's code + the console + an example tree is posted here: http://pastebin.com/9nXvcCNS

Comment: To mark a question "solved", please add an answer below, and then "accept" it with the green checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are trying to actually do here, as your code is messy and fussy. You need to understand that when you return a value from a recursive function call, it will return it to a point from where it has previously been called.

If you have a structure like this,

```
a 
| - b 
    | - c
```

where each item is represented as

```
class Node{
    String data;
    Node nextNode;

}
```

and would like your list to contain Strings "a", "b", and "c", you wold have to write something like this:

```
List<String> allDirectories = new ArrayList<String>();
getDirectories(allDirectories);

private void getDirectories(List<String> allDirectories) {
     //somehow get next node
     Node node = getNextNode();
    //if next node is null, or terminating node: return
    if (node == null) return;
    allDirectories.add(node.getData());
    getDirectories(allDirectories);

}
```

In other words, try passing your list as a parameter to a method, and don't reset it at the beginning of a function call.